# Best practices for model instance 'utility functions' in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing up a few utility functions to avoid rewriting some code in several views for use with a model's instances. Is it safe/best practice/pythonic to add these functions to the model's class definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely - that's part of the point of having models as classes.